# Pass a group of IDs to function (onchange function)

Tags: javascript, variables, checkbox

I have 10 html table lines. In each line I have 1 checkbox and 2 input boxes, each element with an unique ID (AA, Price_1, RTprice_1, AB, Price_2, RTprice_2....AJ, Price_10, RTprice_10)

Trying to disable the corresponding input fields once a checkbox is checked. I'm repeating the function for each line. How can I pass each group of variable into the below function instead of having 10 functions? Script:

```
document.getElementById("AA").onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('price_1').disabled = !this.checked;
document.getElementById('RTprice_1').disabled = !this.checked;
document.getElementById('price_1').value = "0";
document.getElementById('RTprice_1').value = "0";
document.getElementById('AA').value = "0";
};  

                                       
document.getElementById("AB").onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('price_2').disabled = !this.checked;
document.getElementById('RTprice_2').disabled = !this.checked;
document.getElementById('price_2').value = "0";
document.getElementById('RTprice_2').value = "0";
document.getElementById('AB').value = "0";};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id='1' onchange="changeUI(1)" />                    // AA
   <input class='inputfield' id='inputfield1-1' />         // price_1
   <input class='inputfield' id='inputfield1-2'/>          // RTprice_1

<input id='2' onchange="changeUI(2)" />                   // AB
   <input class='inputfield' id='inputfield1-2'/>         // price_2
   <input class='inputfield' id='inputfield1-2'/>         // RTprice_2
... 
<input id='10' onchange="changeUI(10)" />
   ...
```

Your function

```
function changeUI(x) {
    var id = x;
    $('.inputfield').hide();
    
    $('#inputfield1-' + x).show();
    $('#inputfield2-' + x).show();

    $('#inputfield1-' + x).val("0");
    $('#inputfield2-' + x).val("0");
    $('#' + x).val("0");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting each input individually, iterate over `tr`s and execute the toggle script.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#yourTable');
const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

rows.forEach((item) => {
    const txtCheckbox = item.querySelector('.txtCheckbox');
    const inputs = item.querySelector('.txtInput');

    txtCheckbox.addEventListener('change', e => {
        if(e.currentTarget.checked) {
            // Any other script if checkbox is unchecked.
            inputs.forEach((input) => input.removeAttribute('readonly'));
        } else {
            // Any other script if checkbox is checked.
            inputs.forEach((input) => input.setAttribute('readonly', true));
        }
    });
});
```